# Use a 'for' loop for the 'aggregate' command?

Tags: r, loops, aggregate-functions

I've got a data frame as so,

```
Treatment Type  Numerical Value
1          A          3
1          B          2
1          A          8
1          B          7
2          B          4
2          B          1
2          A          2
2          A          2
```

I want to make a table of means for each type and treatments.

Using aggregate, I have: `aggregate(df[,3], list(Treatment) ,mean)` which gives me the means for each treatment but not separated by type too. I was thinking this could be rectified by a for-loop.

Note: This is just a subset of the data, and the list of numerical values is hundreds for each type and treatment.

Comment: ```aggregate(`Numerical Value` ~ Treatment + Type, df, mean)```? Haven't tested but should work

Comment: Yeah works for the subset, but for some reason when I apply to the whole set I get the error: `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have repu to comment:

```
aggregate(df, list(Treatment,Type), mean)
```

Comment: But I've already commented

Comment: I did not see your comment when I answered ,I can take down the answer if thats the norm

Comment: You don't need to *take down anything*, I'm just referring to the title of the answer.

Comment: I meant that If I had repu to comment i would not have answered it

Comment: @E1993 if this worked for you ,perhaps you could accept this answer :)